# Angular 2 CRUD Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angular, crud

I want to do a simple crud application. I have two components - employee-list and add-employee. Add-employee component is added to employee-list component and employee-list component is added to the app component.

In the add-employee component I have a Bootstrap modal that emits data to employee-list and it is being added to an array. (a model with its properties) I want to edit this data using again Bootstrap modal but it gives me an error of undefined id. When I try to add a second modal my data disappears.

employee-list.TS

```
employeesList: Employee [];

 constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onAddEmployee(employee: Employee) {
    this.employeesList.push(employee);
  }
  onDeleteEmployee(i) {
    this.employeesList.splice(i, 1);
  }
```

employee-list.HTML

```
<app-edit-employees-modal (employeeAdded)="onAddEmployee($event)"></app-edit-employees-modal>
<table class="table table-sm">
    <h2>Employees</h2>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let employee of employeesList; let i= index">
        <td> {{ employee.id }} </td>
        <td> {{ employee.name }} </td>
        <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="onEditEmployee(i)">Edit</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onDeleteEmployee(i)">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Who gives you an error of undefined id? When? In which line of code?

Comment: When I try to add another form in which I can update the data I already have.

Comment: Sorry man, still not clear enough. What *another* form? You already have one form in a modal, as far as I understood. Does this one work? There used to be issues with modal components in Angular, I suggest you first try making the form non-modal and see if that works.